# power function in pari library

Tags: math, pari

I am trying to use the PARI library for C. I am new to it. Whenever I try to use any function I get a segmentation fault or stack overflow error. Can anyone please provide me a link with detailed functionality of all constructs and functions in PARI? I want to use sets and vectors also. Is there any function like power of *x*?

Answer (score 1):

There are several powring functions in PARI.  `powii` takes to `GEN` pointers representing integers and returns a `GEN` representing the power.  `gpow` takes any two `GEN`s and returns their power.  `powuu` takes two `uint`s and returns a `GEN`. And so forth.

See the [User's Guide to the PARI Library](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/manuals/2.5.0/libpari.pdf) for more details.  There are links to tutorials at

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:PARI/GP#Resources

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow depends on how much RAM you have. I have an 8-GB RAM PC and my stack can go up close to 1000 MB:

```
(12:14) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 8000000 (7.629 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 16000000 (15.259 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 32000000 (30.518 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 64000000 (61.035 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 128000000 (122.070 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 256000000 (244.141 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 512000000 (488.281 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 1024000000 (976.563 Mbytes).
(12:18) gp > allocatemem
  ***   Warning: not enough memory, new stack 1024000000.
  ***   Warning: new stack size = 1024000000 (976.563 Mbytes).
```

If you go past that and still get stack overflow, it's probably too much for Pari/GP to handle.

Then there is the [documentation](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/doc.html).